# Is there a way to print a column in python using a SQL data structure?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have been set a task to write a table using SQL about my friends. This is the code.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = lite.connect('test.db')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()


cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Freinds")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Friends(FirstName TEXT, LastName TEXT, Age INT, Gender TEXT)")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Friends VALUES('Tom', 'Collins', 14, 'Male')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Friends VALUES('Zak', 'Baker', 14, 'Male')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Friends VALUES('Matt', 'Breeze', 14, 'Male')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Friends VALUES('Lara', 'Nevins', 14, 'Female')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Friends VALUES('David', 'Fawole', 14, 'Not Sure')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Friends VALUES('Emma', 'Williams', 14, 'Female')")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO Friends VALUES('Bailey', 'West', 14, 'Male')")

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print(row)

cur2 = con .cursor()
cur2.execute("SELECT * FROM Friends LIMIT 5")

rs = cur2.fetchall()
print("print top five records only")

for row in rs:
    print(row)

# cur2.execute("SELECT * FROM Friends ")
```

In the last line of code I would like to print the column Gender but only the names that are Male.

Answer (score 0):

Did you really mean to print column Gender? Or maybe FirstName? If so, here you go:

```
for row in cur.execute("SELECT FirstName FROM Friends WHERE Gender='Male''"):
    print(row)
```

Comment: This was written in portable python 3 so some of the code isn't what it usually is. So were would I put that line of code. I'm really new to coding, sorry.

Comment: BTW. You don't need new cursor.